# MUI V5 Variant Overrides

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to add to the variant within MUIPaper and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The types on the component are:

```
variant?: OverridableStringUnion<'elevation' | 'outlined', PaperPropsVariantOverrides>;
```

How do I extend the variant prop using PaperPropsVariantOverrides. My expected outcome is:

```
variant?: 'elevation' | 'outlined' | 'grey' | 'white',
```

Component: `Paper.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import MUIPaper, { PaperProps as MuiPaperProps } from '@mui/material/Paper';
import { PaperPropsVariantOverrides } from '@mui/material';

export interface PaperPropsVariantOverrides {
  variant: 'grey' | 'white';
}

export type PaperProps = MuiPaperProps;

const Paper: React.FC<PaperProps> = (props) => {
  const { ...paperProps } = props;

  return <MUIPaper variant="grey" {...paperProps} />;
};
export default Paper;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can extend by declaring the override module like so:

```
declare module '@mui/material/Paper' {
  interface PaperPropsVariantOverrides {
    myAwesomeVariant: true;
  }
}
```

then inside of your theme you can define the style for the variant:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiPaper: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: "myAwesomeVariant" },
          style: { border: "1px solid red" },
        },
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Then you should be able to use it

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Paper variant="myAwesomeVariant">Stuff</Paper>
</ThemeProvider>
```

It's described better here https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#adding-new-component-variants

Comment: This solution isn't working for me. I have `typings.d.ts` in my src folder, and have setup the declare, however I'm still getting an error that my new variant isn't available. Is there some pitfall many people miss here?

Comment: It seems I had to add the declare somewhere else, I put it in my theme file and it's working. I'm not sure what the difference is.

Answer (score -2):

```
<MUIPaper variant="grey" {...paperProps} />
```

No need the interface. just add a CSS with the class like ".MuiPaper-grey", the the style will be change

https://mui.com/api/paper/

[image: variant?]

Comment: This is a possible solution, however, I would prefer to create a variant.

Comment: https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#adding-new-component-variants sure you can make it harder.